# COUNT joining two tables by two columns

Tags: mysql

I need a help with this: Use COUNT to determine how many instances there are of each sku associated with each store in the
skstinfo table and the trnsact table?

You should find relevant relational scheme here [Relational scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enilz.jpg)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the structure of the two tables and your query so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use subquery for that:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(skuinfo.id) skuinfo WHERE skuinfo.sku = sksinfo.sku) AS totalSku FROM sksinfo
```

Comment: The outcome is: Error Occurred . . .
[com.teradata.commons.datatools.sqlparsers.common.ParseException: Encountered "," at line 7, column 9. Was expecting one of: "except" ... "expand" ... "for" ... "from" ... "group" ... "having" ... "intersect" ... "into" ... "minus" ... "order" ... "qualify" ... "sample" ... "union" ... "where" ... "with" ... ";" ... "." ... , com.teradata.commons.datatools.sqlparsers.common.ParseException: Encountered ")" at line 7, column 76. Was expecting one of: "and" ... "at" ... "day" ... "except" ... "expand" ... "for" ... "from" ... "group" ... "having" ...